# How to modify biblatex authoryear article entry to have period after date but commas between title, journal, and pages

Tags: biblatex

After adding tweaks from other answers here (thanks!) I managed to get `authoryear` article entries to be like this:

> Russell, Bertrand (1905). “On Denoting”. *Mind*, vol. 14, no. 56,
>   479–493.

But I need one more tweak: a comma between the article title and the journal name, so to have:

> Russell, Bertrand (1905). “On Denoting”, *Mind*, vol. 14, no. 56,
>   479–493.

I currently invoke biblatex using:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

And in biblatex.cfg I have:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}%

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}%

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Comma before and after journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Prefixes for journal volume and number
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal
```

Comment: Maybe you just want `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}` together with `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addperiod\space}`?

Comment: Or you go with `\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{\setunit{\addcomma\space}}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}` inestead.

Comment: A few words to the two solutions. The first one will convert almost all periods to commas in the bibliography. Since you seem to already have done this it might do what you want. But it might not do the right thing for non-`@articles`. The second solution then is specific to `@articles` only and makes sure a comma is inserted before the `journaltitle` (given a `journaltitle` is present, but you would think so in an `@article`, wouldn't you). (If any of the two helped, a short heads up would be nice, I could prepare a full answer then.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The first made me realize I didn't give a full description of the problem. For the OUP house style I'm following I do need periods after all units for books. E.g.

Lewis, C. I. (1918). A Survey of Symbolic Logic. Semicentennial publications of the University of
California, 1868-1918. Berkeley, CA: University of California Press.

But alas solution 2 is not working. I get an inputenc error:

Unicode char \u8:​ not set up for use with LaTeX.

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

works fine.

Comment: Maybe when you copied the code from this site you copied some junk character. What happens if you type in the `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` by hand?

Comment: You're absolutely right.  It works like a charm! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want the change applied to `@articles` the best course of action is probably to inject the comma into the `in:` macro like so

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
```

This inserts a comma into the punctuation buffer overwriting the period residing there (for `@article`s only).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}%

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}%

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}


% Comma before and after journal volume
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

% Prefixes for journal volume and number
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

\begin{document}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]